# To tell git about removed files

Tags: git

I have removed some files in project with `rm` command (`not git rm`). What is the easiest way to tell about it to git and commit?

Comment: `git add /path/to/remove/file /path/to/other/removed/file`

Comment: If you have no other changes use `git add --all`. If you do have other changes that you don't want to stage, and if you're on Linux and the filenames contain no spaces you can use `git add -- $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only)`